# Comparing SHA-256 checksums: how many characters do I need to check?

Tags: checksum, sha

Checksums are useful for verifying that a file, such as a downloaded dmg, has not been changed. But it's tedious to examine the entire checksum, since a SHA-256 checksum has 64 hex characters. Fortunately, the algorithm is designed such that two files with a small difference in content will have very different checksums.

Still, I want to be sure, so just how many characters do I need to compare to safely verify that two files are identical? Is it sufficient to compare, say, the first or last 5 characters?

Comment: Remember to choose an answer if you believe one is correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick**

You should check every character. You shouldn't check it on your own. For Windows/Powershell use this:

```
get-filehash ./relativeLocationOfFileToCompare | select -expandproperty hash | compare-object theHashYouWantToCompare
```

i.e.

```
get-filehash ./kali-linux-2020.4-vbox-i386.ova | select -expandproperty hash | compare-object 64f6ca69ccb3efc79e350977d33109c380a744c26158c4e3956141535242e2ca
```

**More**

You need to check every character, for malicious parties can create partial collisions i.e. the first 20 characters are the same.

**My understanding of why checksums are used**

You want software. You go to the actual supplier website i.e. kali.org. You click to download software. Kali.org doesn't actually send you the software; they tell your browser to go to their cdn and download the software. The cdn is a slightly un-trusted third party. The cdn could've gone rogue, or the cdn could be compromised. What to do.

Kali.org is not compromised (if kali is, there are bigger issues and checksumming isn't used to combat them). Therefore, you can obtain the valid checksum from Kali.org. You get the hash and compare every character with the one-liner I provided. You've protected yourself from non-collisions, part-collisions, and you've probably saved some time by not comparing each character manually.

Comment: This is exactly the checksum use case I was asking about. Thank you for your clear explanation of why we need to validate the entire hash.

Answer (score 0):

Why use SHA-256 if you don't check all the bytes? There are shorter functions like SHA1, MD5, etc.

- If you're writing a software that checks the checksums - you must check all of the bytes of the hash
- If you're talking about manual comparison by eye - then to be sure use copy+find in order to check them. Letter-by-letter comparison is more error prone.

Eventually how many characters you want to check depends on how badly you want to be correct and how many files you have. There's probably no right answer.

But I'd assume that yes - for most practical purposes checking first 5 characters is sufficient. I don't know the math behind SHA256 but if we assume that all characters are equally probable then it's going to be 1 in 16⁵ (roughly 1 in a million) chance that different files get the same 5 letters of hash. Which are pretty good odds if you have 100 files.

PS: Git chooses to use 7 characters for the short version of SHA1.

PPS: SHA256 is used in cryptography/security. If it's just about file integrity for a typical hands-on task - shorter and less secure hash functions will be perfectly suitable.

Comment: My use case, which I think is pretty common, is to quickly eyeball the checksum of a downloaded installer to avoid malware. The reason for not using using SHA1 or MD5 is that they have been successfully attacked (see Wikipedia).

Comment: @prefectionist by "attacked" they mean it's possible to come up with another string which has the same hash, which would allow an attacker to _sign_ the data as if they had the private key of Certification Authority. It's not about integrity of downloaded file - SHA256 won't help you with the malware problem (if a hacker fooled you in downloading the malware - it will fool you in downloading the checksum _for the malware_). Also "more secure" and "use only first N characters" are mutually exclusive :)

Comment: @<a href=https://stackoverflow.com/users/886697/stanislav-bashkyrtsev>Stanislav</a> good point: it's essential to get the checksum from a reliable source (e.g. the creator of the software and not a third party). As far as being secure, one can always do more or less, so _caveat emptor_. But sometimes practical rules of thumb are helpful, eh?

Comment: @prefectionist, it doesn't depend on the reliability of the source. Checksums are simply not used for security, they are a means to check if the file was downloaded correctly (every bit was delivered w/o errors). _Signatures_ are what's used for security purposes. As for practical rule of thumb to compare the checksums, as I mentioned in the answer: 5-7 characters is probably good enough. But it's always a risk nonetheless, so then - why bother checking checksums at all ;)

Comment: checksums are not used for security? Why do sites such as CRAN include statements like this: "Please check the MD5 checksum of the downloaded image to ensure that it has not been tampered with or corrupted during the mirroring process."?

Comment: @prefectionist, well okay - if you download a binary from a 3d party site (mirror) but the checksum is downloaded from the main site - this is a security usage too, you're right. I can't say it's a typical situation, but a possible one. Though if you keep reading docs on CRAN site it gives you a better alternative for this: _On Mac OS X 10.7 and later you can also validate the signature using pkgutil --check-signature R-4.0.3.pkg_ (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/). Also note that hash functions _are_ used in security protocols (e.g. for signing), just not in a way you use them.

Comment: okay thanks for explaining the most common uses of checksums, and for pointing out alternatives when it comes to file security (i,.e. avoiding tampered files). I guess my use case is not as common as  I thought.